# How to minus / subtract the values after getting their sum in mysql

Tags: php

I want to get value from sum of dueamount, sum of received amount as well remaining amount . first two answers are being retrieved but remaining amount(which will come from the subtraction of those two values) is not coming from the query. Please help me.

$query= "SELECT SUM(dueamount) AS dueamount,SUM(receivedamount) AS received, 
    'SUM(dueamount)'-'SUM(receivedamount)' AS due from paymentdetails where regno='$regno';

Comment: What's the question???

Comment: Just a quick question you do have that string enclosed in double quotes on your live version right? `$query= "SELECT SUM(dueamount) AS dueamount,SUM(receivedamount) AS received, 'SUM(dueamount)'-'SUM(receivedamount)' AS due from paymentdetails where regno='$regno'";` <- Notice the " at the end.

Comment: Does it return an empty field? Does is it give an error. Can you be more specific.

Comment: no error. it returns correct sum of dueamount and sum of receivedamount but their difference returns 0

Comment: there are " in the end. there is no error but not getting my all values. it should return 3 values. it is returning 2 values but it is returning 0 instead of 3rd value

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$query= "SELECT SUM(dueamount) AS dueamount, SUM(receivedamount) AS received, 
dueamount - received AS due from paymentdetails where regno='$regno';
```

Answer (score 0):

Its the single quote thats causing the issue, single quote should be around column name not the whole aggregate function because it consider it a string liternal then so no subraction is performed on two numbers but literals which result in 0.

```
$query= "SELECT SUM(dueamount) AS dueamount,SUM(receivedamount) AS received, SUM('dueamount')-SUM('receivedamount') AS due from paymentdetails where regno='$regno'
```

Hope it helped.